# How to update datetimes in sql server from local to universal time

Tags: sql-server, date, timezone

I've been storing date times in local time and I need to convert them all to Universal time.

How can I do this in SQL Server 2008?

By local time, I mean either BST or GMT.

i.e. I stored `DateTime.Now()` from .NET throughout the year, and I now need to homogenise the data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

please consider sending already from the c# the utc

also, there is `SELECT  GETUTCDATE()`

in sql server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx

### edit

if you need to update so

```
UPDATE SomeTable
   SET DateTimeStamp = DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), DateTimeStamp)
```

Comment: wont this do so considering the CURRENT (i.e. at the time i run the command) time zone? i.e. `1/7/2011 01:00:00` was in BST, so i need to turn it into `1/7/2011 00:00:00`. but 11/1/2011 01:00:001 is in GMT, so does not need to be changed. I havent stored the timezone :(

Comment: @AndrewBullock If you havent stored the timezone so you are out of luck.....sorry.... there is no way to know from which timezone it was created......

Comment: @AndrewBullock do you have the request user agent  string ? ( of the old records ) ?

Comment: no, but good idea! i'll just have to find out the timezone changes and adjust the data in batches, ive only got a few years of changes so there should only be 5 batches or so.

Comment: re "no way to know", the only ones that i dont know are the ones between the timezone change (i.e. where there are 2x the same hour in a day. they were all `NOW` dates, so they were made when they were made

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function of SQL Server.  You just have to know to no. of hours difference from your local to time to UTC.

Comment: what Royi said, is there a way to do it without me having to work out what all the time changes were manually? (i.e. when they happened)